# MEF2 in .Net Core 2.0 error

Tags: c#, .net-core, mef

I have a class FunctionExtender.cs

```
[Export(typeof(IFunctionsExtender))]
public class FunctionExtender : IFunctionsExtender
{
    private static IOptions<Settings> _settings;       
    private static ILogger<FunctionExtender> _logger;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public FunctionExtender(IOptions<Settings> settings, ILogger<FunctionExtender> logger)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

and trying to use it with MEF2

```
var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(path, "Abc.Xacml.*.dll")
  .Select(p => AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(p))
  .Where(x => x != null);

var configuration = new ContainerConfiguration()
  .WithAssemblies(assemblies);

var container = configuration.CreateContainer();

var exportedTypes = container.GetExports<IFunctionsExtender>(); // exception is here
foreach (var t in exportedTypes) {
    var extensionTypes = t.GetExtensionFunctions();
    foreach (var extensionType in extensionTypes) {
        functions.Add(extensionType.Key, extensionType.Value);
    }
}
```

and I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Composition.Hosting.CompositionFailedException' occurred in System.Composition.Hosting.dll
>
> Additional information: No export was found for the contract 'IOptions< Settings>'
>   -> required by import 'settings' of part 'DoctorFunctionExtender'
>   -> required by import 'item' of part 'IFunctionsExtender[]'
>   -> required by initial request for contract 'IFunctionsExtender[] { IsImportMany = True }'

How this problem could be solved?